# Spring Mobile: how to add DeviceWebArgumentResolver programmatically?

Tags: java, configuration, spring-mobile

Spring mobile [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-mobile/docs/1.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/) suggest adding the following configuration:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:argument-resolvers>
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceWebArgumentResolver" />
    </mvc:argument-resolvers>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

to pass the current Device object as an argument to `@Controller` methods.

Yet, one can use:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

}
```

and bypass `<mvc:annotation-driven>` configuration.

Then, how to add a `DeviceWebArgumentResolver` programmatically?

**Solution (Luciano):**

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(
        List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {

        // Adding Spring mobile argument resolvers
        argumentResolvers.add(
            new ServletWebArgumentResolverAdapter(
                new DeviceWebArgumentResolver()));

        argumentResolvers.add(
            new ServletWebArgumentResolverAdapter(
                new SitePreferenceWebArgumentResolver()));

    }

    // ...

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` contains a method named `addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers)`

That is the method you need to implement, but first you need to convert a `WebArgumentResolver` (in this case, `DeviceWebArgumentResolver`) into a `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`. For that, there exists a class named `ServletWebArgumentResolverAdapter`.

Comment: As of the 1.1.0.M1 release, Spring Mobile now includes a `DeviceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` to support Java-based configuration.